# foreign key model value in template

Tags: django

Is there anything that would prevent access to the default User model ?

Model:

```
class Chart( models.Model ):
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 255 )
    author = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'the_author' )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False )

    def __str__( self ):
        return self.title
```

The other model is User, from djangoALLauth. I didn't created this model, but is has an 'email' field I want to access.

The view that build the template:

```
def home( request ):
    """Home page handling"""

    most_favorited_charts = Chart.objects.order_by( '-favorites_count' )[ :10 ]
    newest_charts = Chart.objects.order_by( '-created_at' )[ :10 ]

    context = {
        "js_dow_data" : jsdow_data( ),
        "most_favorited_charts": most_favorited_charts,
        "newest_charts": newest_charts,
        "submit_value": "Save"
    }
```

The template. I want to get the 'email' from User model, which is referenced as a foreign key from the Chart model as shown above. Here is the latest attempt from many other. See the block where I try to produce 'Email:" content:

```
 {% for chart in most_favorited_charts %}
                        <div class="user-charts-links-div"><a class="chart-title" href="#">{{ chart.title }}</a>

                            {% for author in chart.the_author.all %}
                                Email: {{ author.the_author.email }}<br>
                            {% endfor %}


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

It produces nothing and I can't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation is the other way round from what you seem to think. It goes from Chart to User; that is, each chart has one author, and you access it via the field name rather than the reverse relation.

Replace your for loop with a simple lookup:

```
Email: {{ chart.author.email }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried {{ chart.author_id.email }} with 'author_id' being the foreign key field name, but would not have imagined that I could directly access User fields from the chart instance.

Comment: Why not? You explicitly defined a field with that name.